# get user's youtube account playlist in rails 3 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, youtube

i want to get a user's playlist from his youtube account in my rails 3 application. after sign-up the user enters his details. m accepting his youtube handle and want to display the different playlists that the user has created on youtube.
  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you might have a look at this gem https://github.com/kylejginavan/youtube_it.

It seems to be pretty feature complete, has some decent tests, good documentation and even a example Rails app https://github.com/chebyte/youtube_it_rails_app_example.